# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>' at $response line

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm writing a code to fetch data from my google sheets using Google Sheets API and PHP but my data is not shown and I get ran error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function makeApiCall() {
  
    // The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
    $spreadsheetId: '1wcNmi2hgz30gx1zjrKDgMNrxf1mPPFXbp7g_WRpK9Hw';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
    $range: 'Data1!A2:H';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // How values should be represented in the output.
    // The default render option is ValueRenderOption.FORMATTED_VALUE.
    // $valueRenderOption: '';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

    // How dates, times, and durations should be represented in the output.
    // This is ignored if value_render_option is
    // FORMATTED_VALUE.
    // The default dateTime render option is [DateTimeRenderOption.SERIAL_NUMBER].
    // $dateTimeRenderOption: '';  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
  
    $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
    $values = $response->getValues();
    if (empty($values)) {
        print "No data found.\n";
    } else {
        foreach ($values as $row) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            printf("%s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\n", $row[0], $row[1],$row[2],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5],$row[6],$row[7]);
        }
    }
}

function initClient() {
    var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyAOFUNhuXlOxPBTmkqUEyxnEkG8mnR9N7k';  // TODO: Update placeholder with desired API key.

    var CLIENT_ID = '289763823878-c2pfkf7g9plaup99v4p42fncnm3on188.apps.googleusercontent.com';  // TODO: Update placeholder with desired client ID.

    // TODO: Authorize using one of the following scopes:
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly';

    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'clientId': CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': SCOPE,
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4'],
    }).then(function() {
        makeApiCall();
    });
}

</script>
```

I'm still beginner and its been a week since I got this problem, can someone help me?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Error messages normally include a clue to where the error is is there MORE to this error than you showed us `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'`

Comment: Why you use php code inside javascript code ?

Comment: Your `printf()` has more values than place holders :)

Comment: Thank you for that, I didn't realize about that..

Answer (score 0):

### `<script></script>` can only be used to include javascript code into an html file

- Thus, any code pasted within those tags will be read as javascript.
- `->` is not a valid javascript operator and this is why the code throws you here the (first) error

If what you are trying to achieve is t embed php code into your html - the process is different:

- Save your php code in a separate file located ont he server
- Use [`<?php include 'footer.php';?>`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) tags to include this file into your HTML code